# Reproduce character pattern as numeric pattern

Tags: r, design-patterns

I would like to expand the following data frame

```
d <- data.frame(a = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5),rep("C",3),rep("D",2)))

> d
   a
1  A
2  A
3  A
4  A
5  A
6  B
7  B
8  B
9  B
10 B
11 C
12 C
13 C
14 D
15 D
```

so that there is a column b looking like:

```
> d
   a b
1  A 1
2  A 1
3  A 1
4  A 1
5  A 1
6  B 2 
7  B 2 
8  B 2
9  B 2
10 B 2
11 C 3
12 C 3
13 C 3
14 D 4
15 D 4
```

Not really sure how to realise that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use match:

```
match(d$a, unique(d$a))
```

Comment: Clever. I like this better too.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien it's essentially exactly what your solution does under the covers

Answer (score 2):

```
d$b <- as.integer(factor(d$a, levels=unique(d$a)))
```

Comment: +1 Remind me next time to first post the code, then edit and add the results! PS. You can simplify this to `as.integer(factor(d$a))`

Comment: hello, that works but only partially. If one swaps around B and D for instance, then D still gets the number 4 but should get two instead. My example was probably not very good as the letters A to D are in alphabetical order. sorry

Comment: @user969113 See my edit, which should work with any ordering of the letters.

Comment: Hey, @Andrie. Remember: next time, first post code and **then** edit and add results =)